# Task Tracking software

Tags: c#, .net, project-management, issue-tracking

I'm looking for a task tracking application for various coding activities.

Generally, i am not against online services, however we should be managing internal tools development for our company, and so i prefer it to be software that is installed locally.

Requirements that i could think of:

1. Integration with current tools (Visual Studio 2008/2010).
2. Integration with SCM (moving to Git soon).
3. Easily get listings/graphs of tasks with scheduling options.
4. Other fancy features that u may suggest?

EDIT: Forgot to add the most important one i guess, which is PRICE.
I do not think we can opt for a TFS budget, allthough i am not sure what are the costs of it for a very small dev-team.

What are your recommendations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS Task management integrates nicely with Source Control, Build, and Test Management.  I would check that out if you haven't already.

Comment: Actually i double checked and TFS appears to be included in our company's MSDN subscription. Does it integrate with Git? or it enforces its own source control system?

Comment: It includes its own source control system.  I used TFS for years, and just changed jobs to a company that uses Git.  I know others will disagree, but I think TFS source control is at least as capable as Git.  Specifically if you are not like a GUI over a terminal.  But TFS does have a terminal interface, if that's how you roll...

Answer (score 4):

Try [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com/). It is free for 5 users.

Here is the [Feature List](http://www.targetprocess.com/Product/Features.aspx) for you.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/for-your-server.html) and love it. It supports [Git integration](http://blog.fogcreek.com/git-integration/), though the developers of FogBugz also offer Mercurial SCM through a product called [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/) that integrates nicely with FogBugz.

FogBugz also includes [Visual Studio integration](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?W984), among other [features](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/features/project-management.html).

Comment: Fogbugz is an externally hosted product or can we install it locally Also is it free?

Comment: Both. They have a hosted version as well as self-hosted licensing (http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/for-your-server.html). It's not free, though, but you do get a lot for the money. You can get it for free if you're a student or startup (2 or less people): http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/StudentAndStartup.html

Comment: vs integration with fogbugz only allows viewing current issues. All operations require logging into the site with the browser...

Answer (score 1):

We use [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) here and love it. It has VS 2008/10 integration and SCM (SVN & Git) and outlook.
What we love about it is that is has testing baked in so we can track requirements, tasks and testing all with one tool.

It also has nice visual project planner that helps with resource and release planning.

Comment: I can also recommend Gemini. We have been using it for years and have recently partnered with Countersoft to build a financial tracking Add-on for it. Have a look here - http://www.collectivematters.com/2011/06/increasing-project-profitability/

Answer (score -1):

All of these tools are good, but I figured I would throw in Axosoft's OnTime into the mix.

It integrates directly in VS and has most, if not all of the features you needed above.

You can check it out at http://www.axosoft.com/

They offer both a hosted and installed version and their beta just came out recently, so you can actually try OnTime out for free.

Great of task management and bug tracking.

Cheers